# In browserslist, what is the point of having different environments configurations?

Tags: javascript, webpack, configuration, environment-variables

**Introduction**: `browserslist` is a configuration for letting other developers, packages, plugins, etc., know which browsers your project gives support to. This is done through queries, and there is a way to split these queries into different environments.

```
{
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
}
```

Let's say I use a javascript function that is supported by the development config, but not by production.

**My question is**: then what is the point of having split config between production and development if I would find possible errors for production config that are not detected earlier in development? (Is it because it gives speed on compiling time or some similar advantage?)

Answer (score 0):

**Production**: This will minify your code for **fast** web performance and has a feature for production-built-in

eg. at your CSS styling you should wrap all your CSS code in a file or [MiniCssExtractPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/mini-css-extract-plugin/) when you decided to deploy your project

**Development**: This will give the productivity when building your project

eg. you should have a [DevServer](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/) and [StylingLoaders](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/#styling) to put styling at the **DOM**  and when you deploy the project you can implement the [Css Plugin to create a file](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/mini-css-extract-plugin/)

Your **production config** gives you an error because it may need to update some dependencies or npm packages

Comment: I understand the differences between production and development environments. My question is more related to finding **possible** errors or incompatibilities, according to certain browsers. E.g.: if I want to support IE 10 in prod but it does not work with some css properties I use, how could I detect that using 
`"development": [ "last 1 chrome version","last 1 firefox version","last 1 safari version" ]` ?
Shouldn't I include IE10 in that array? Or is it handled internally by other loaders like babel using browserslist?